# ¿Por que comandos en Composer empiezan con "php"?

Tags: composer

yo he instalado composer con el installer de windows y veo que para usar install se debe usar   `php composer install miProyecto`   pero (yo uso windows, quizá sea diferente aqui) esto de indica que no hay tal comando composer. Sin embargo si uso `composer install miProyecto` funciona perfectamente. ¿Qué diferencia hay en usar o no php antes de los comandos?

Comment: composer es una herramienta hecha en php. Si tienes en tu sistema un interprete de php, la herramienta tiene permisos de ejecucion y el interprete se puede localizar en tu PATH, puedes invocarla directamente con el nombre. (`composer install...`) En caso de no tener el interprete en tus rutas PATH, el sistema no seria capaz de ejecutarlo. Tendrias que llamar directamente al interprete (esto seria algo como `/usr/bin/php composer install...`.

Comment: @Jakala deberías poner eso como respuesta.

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro ¿cómo se pone esto como respuesta? Me gustaría hacerlo pero la verdad es que no veo opciones para ello. Lo único que puedo hacer es votarlo como comentario útil pero no veo como ponerlo como respuesta. ¿Podrías decirme como?

Comment: @RicardoKra Debe haber un botón en la parte de abajo de la página que ponga "Responde a tu pregunta", púlsalo y acepta el mensajito que sale. A partir de ahí se abrirá la zona de respuestas también para ti.

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro Yo creo que le corresponde a Jakala hacerlo ya que fue él quien la respondió (no me fijé que tu comentario era para él). Si no lo hace en las próximas 48 horas entonces lo pondré como respuesta. ¿Te parece que así sea correcto?

Comment: Suena perfecto. Gracias por la ayuda :)

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta de Jakala:
composer es una herramienta hecha en php. Si tienes en tu sistema un interprete de php, la herramienta tiene permisos de ejecucion y el interprete se puede localizar en tu PATH, puedes invocarla directamente con el nombre. (composer install...) En caso de no tener el interprete en tus rutas PATH, el sistema no seria capaz de ejecutarlo. Tendrias que llamar directamente al interprete (esto seria algo como /usr/bin/php composer install....